# Magento 1.9 Live Website Admin Not Working

Tags: authentication, admin, magento-1.9

I am not able to log in to my Magento website admin. I am getting the following error.
Below is the error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Invalid method Mage_Admin_Model_User::login(Array
(
    [0] => admin
    [1] => testT
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(118): Varien_Object->__call('login', Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(118): Mage_Admin_Model_User->login('admin', 'testT')
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('admin', 'testT', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I tried removing var/session and var/cache folders. Also, cleared cookies and sessions from the browser. Magento version is 1.9. Still getting the same error. Does anyone know how to fix it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow the below instructions to fix this:

Delete the generated/code directory rm -rf generated/code

Then run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> chmo -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/